# tensorflow estimator training only runs half of the steps

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm having a problem with TF Estimators generated from keras. I've added in a SessionRunHook to display which step is being run. Both evaluate() and predict() both run the correct number of steps, but train() only runs half the number of steps that I tell it to, e.g. I if specify enough steps for 2 epochs, it runs 1. If I specify enough steps for 4 epochs, it runs 2.

Here's the relevant code snippets. First my input function. I use the same input function for train, evaluate and predict:

```
def input_function(features, labels=None, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=1):
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={model.input_names[0] : features},
    y=labels,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    num_epochs=num_epochs,
    shuffle=shuffle)
return input_fn
```

Here's how I call training:

```
steps = np.ceil((nb_epoch * np.ceil(X_train.shape[0] / batch_size).astype(np.int32)) / num_gpus).astype(np.int32)
print("  Steps : ", steps, "\n")
time_hist = TimeHistory(num_steps = steps, stage_name='Training')
est_model.train(input_fn=input_function(X_train, y_train, shuffle=True, 
     num_epochs=nb_epoch), steps=steps, hooks=[time_hist])
```

time_hist is my SessionRunHook, and basically counts the steps and print progress. So when I run training on my dataset I get:

```
TRAINING MODEL

  Training dataset size :  39209
  Batch size :  128
  Epochs :  2
  Num GPUs :  1

  Steps :  614

Begin  Training ...
Step :  10 / 614
Step :  20 / 614
...
Step :  290 / 614
Step :  300 / 614
Training  finished.
  total time :  25.3624458313
  avg batch time :  0.08234560334837282
  num steps :  308
```

So it calculated (correctly) that it wold take 614 steps to run 2 epochs of 128 batch_size on the dataset of 39209 elements. I pass steps=614 into train() but it only runs for 308 steps!

When I run evaluate, it works fine:

```
eval_steps = np.ceil((np.ceil(X_test.shape[0] / batch_size).astype(np.int32)) / num_gpus).astype(np.int32)
time_hist = TimeHistory(num_steps = eval_steps, stage_name='Testing')
score = est_model.evaluate(input_fn=input_function(X_test, y_test, shuffle=False), steps=eval_steps, hooks=[time_hist])
```

and I get:

```
TESTING MODEL
   Test dataset size :  12630 
Begin  Testing ... 
Step :  10 / 99 
... 
Step :  80 / 99 
Step :  90 / 99 
Testing  finished.   total time :  3.7828950882   
avg batch time :  0.03821106149692728   
num steps :  99 
Test score :  {'loss': 0.63948023, 'global_step': 616, 'accuracy': 0.8405659}
```

Can anyone please see what I'm doing wrong? Driving me nuts! :)

Update: after some further debug (see notes below), it seems that Tensorboard tells me it has run 616 steps as expected, but the SessionRunHook has only counted half that. Is it possible that SessionRunHook only runs every second step? Some real confusion here between the input_fn num_epochs, the train steps, and tensorboard global_step. Grrrrrr....

Update2 : I added some code to print the global_step_value in my hook, and now it looks like:

```
Begin  Training ...
Step :  10 / 1228
  global_step :  20
Step :  20 / 1228
  global_step :  40
Step :  30 / 1228
  global_step :  60
...
```

So, given that global_step is the number of batches seen by the graph, it seems there is some disjoint between it the steps I'm counting in my hook. Looks like the hook is only called every second global_step. Hrmmm

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Seems as if my input_fn is not able to serve data for the second epoch. That's the only difference between train() and evaluate(); num_epochs is 2 and 1 respectively.

Comment: I kinda stumbled across "an" answer. If I set steps=None in train(), then it seems the input_fn takes control and serves the data correctly for 2 epochs and 614 steps.

Comment: Hrmmm. Something really screwed up here. With steps=None, while it appears to run the right number of steps (614) from the log file, Tensorboard shows that it's actually run 1228 steps. Now I'm wondering if the SessionRunHook is only called once every two steps???